# Search results from only contenttype X

Tags: search

How can I search by some keyword and show the results only from contenttype X? I am using sharepoint 2013.

UPDATE:

I would like to implement this in the search page and not in some search webpart. Because I would like to use also the refiners on the left of the search page.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the search result web part to only display items of your content type.  Just edit the properties of the web part and click "Change Query":

[image]

In quick mode, you can do a query for items by content type.  Quick mode uses drop downs to create the query, and is rather easy.

[image]

In advanced mode, you can use keyword query language.  There are some drop downs to help build the queries.  The following gets all items that inherit from a content type: ContentTypeId:0x0100EEA1F5E3F2E1CA45983B2EAF52D90F4A*

[image]

Comment: And also This part can be used in KeywordQuery or Search API call as the query "ContentTypeId:0x0100EEA1F5E3F2E1CA45983B2EAF52D90F4A*".

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I know this option, but I am looking for some solution on the search page. Because I would like to use also the refiners on the left.

Comment: @KHA This is on the search page.  These changes can be made to the search result web part on the search page.  My screenshots came from a content by search web part, but it's the same for a search results web part.

Comment: Is it possible to make 2 search pages? One with your solution to change the query. And the other like how it is OOTB?

Comment: Just add a new page to the search center Pages library and then use the settings above. Add the page to the navigation verticals by modifying the Search Settings for the site.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a new page in the pages library. I selected the pagelayout "Searchresults". On this page there was a search content webpart which I have edited the query. I have selected a custom source result. This custom source result is filtered on contentype X.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use the content type name by using the ContentType: query in the regular search:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a custom Result Source.

2) In the Query Builder window, add the name of ContentType (e.g. Document)

```
{searchTerms} ContentType=Document
```