# Approaches to create a dashboard-liked page on a site collection level, that shows items from the site collection' subsites

Tags: 2013, list, development, web-part

I have a Team site collection which contain 10 sub-sites, and all these sub sites were created using the same site template. Each sub site have the following 3 lists:-

- Issue tracking list named IssueA.
- Issue tracking list named IssueB.
- A calendar named Calendar.

Now currently end users are facing problems in keeping track of the sub sites' lists. so for example if someone wants to know the pending items assign to him, then he have to go to each subsite , check the related list… which is not very reliable.so I want to know what are the approaches I can follow to create a page on the site collection level that summarize the lists items from all the subsites , for example to have the following :-

- On the site collection home page to view all the items inside IssueA list from all the subsites, that are pending and assign to the login user? So from there the login user can know that there is a pending item assigned to him on subsite ABC ,, without having to check all the subsites’ lists to get this info ?

So can anyone advice how I can do so in sharepoint ?

Comment: You can develop a customized web part using javascript or c#(On-Premise). This web part will show items (filtered by current user) from sub site list like `IssueA`

Comment: @AtishDipongkor so there is not any available built-in options to do so inside SharePoint using available web parts such as  
    Content Search Web Part,
    Search Web Part, or
    Content Query Web Part. i though sharepoint will support such a requirement as all the sub sites are using the same site columns , since as i mentioned before all the subsites were created from the same site template.. or i need to develop my own web part ?

Comment: Content Search Web Part may solve the issue. I did not dig into that yet

Comment: @AtishDipongkor i did not use it either but seems it will allow in a way or another to display items from different lists ,, but not sure if it will allow filtering based on the user name and status...

Answer (score 1):

If each of the lists is based upon their own custom content type (e.g. a custom Issue Tracking Content Type) you can use the Content Query Web Part to roll up your lists.

You can make a Content Type for your Calendars (use the Calendar Item as the parent for this content type) to roll up Calendar lists too.

If they are not based upon a custom content type, you could also use a Content Search Web Part (probably Items Matching a Tag) to look for items where the path contains the Name of your Lists.

You should probably use custom content types in this scenario so you can easily update columns in your lists at the Content Type level, rather than on a list by list basis.

Comment: i am using custom content types for all the 3 lists. but i did not get your point regarding using CT ? i mean what does this have to do in my case?in all ways i think content search web part will work in my case but I am not sure how i can write a query to retrieve all the items that are inside certain list (for example listA) on each sub site + where the item status is pending + the Assign-to attribute = login user? can you adivce on how i can construct such a query ?

Comment: If they are all custom content types you can use the Content Query Web Part to roll up your lists.   This link here might be helpful
https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-d560f477-8fc1-4258-aeb2-70aa932e07da

Comment: If you use the Content Search web part, you can look for all items where content type is equal to your list content type.  This might help you configure the Search > Items Matching a Tag webpart http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96777/search-results-from-only-contenttype-x