# How to exclude the source page from an enterprise keyword search?

Tags: sharepoint-search, keyword

Gentlemen,

Pardon if the question is a bit newbie-ish, but... I have some documents with various enterprise keyword tags, and when I perform a search with keyword:   syntax I get the desired results.... followed by the pages where the documents reside. I would like for this to not happen, and search to return the tagged documents only. Is there an easy GUI way to do this? With query rules, perhaps?   Much obliged in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post that explains how to limit your search results based upon the Content Type of the result (you want Documents only):
[Search results from only contenttype X](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96777/search-results-from-only-contenttype-x)

Comment: Thanks, but that is for a search webpart, right? Where do I make that change for the global search (the search field that is at the topof every site by default, not one i add as a webpart?)

Comment: In your Site Settings menu you should see a link for Result Sources.  Copy the default result source (Local SharePoint Sites) and make the query modification to your new copy.  Then set your copy as the default result source.

Comment: Ah! You are awesome! Thanks James! Now all I gotta do is dig around in KQL until I figure out the syntax to do a local query that excludes URLs...Thanks!